# Upgraded to AppCompat v22.1.0 and now onKeyDown and onKeyUp are not triggered when menu key is pressed

Tags: android, android-support-library, onkeydown, onkeyup

I've just upgraded my app to use the newly released v22.1.0 AppCompat and now `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` are not triggered when menu key is pressed. The other keys correctly trigger `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp`, but when i press the menu key nothing happens. If I downgrade to v22.0.0 everything returns to work properly.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Answering your own question? At the same moment?

Comment: Yes, I followed the advice of this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in the Help Center of Stack Overflow

Comment: It seems onKeyDown and onKeyUp events are now correctly triggered for menu key on AppCompat v22.2.0.

Comment: As [stated](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159795#c20) by Chris Banes the release v22.2 resolves the issue.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Update 23 August**

This [has been fixed](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159795#c31) again in the v23.0.0 of appcompat-v7 support library. Update to the last version to see this fixed.

---

**Update 19 July**

Unfortunately AppCompat v22.2.1 broke the `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` events [again](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159795#c23). I just updated `AppCompatActivityMenuKeyInterceptor` to support v22.1.x and also v22.2.1

---

**Update 29 May**

This [has been fixed](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159795#c20) in the v22.2.0 of appcompat-v7 support library. Update to the last version to see this fixed.

---

Unfortunately AppCompat v22.1.0 intercepts the `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` events and does not propagate them when the menu key is pressed. The only possible solution involves using Reflection to intercept the `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` events before the AppCompat does.

Add this class to your project:

```
public class AppCompatActivityMenuKeyInterceptor {

    private static final String FIELD_NAME_DELEGATE = "mDelegate";
    private static final String FIELD_NAME_WINDOW = "mWindow";

    public static void intercept(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity) {
        new AppCompatActivityMenuKeyInterceptor(appCompatActivity);
    }

    private AppCompatActivityMenuKeyInterceptor(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        try {
            Field mDelegateField = AppCompatActivity.class.getDeclaredField(FIELD_NAME_DELEGATE);
            mDelegateField.setAccessible(true);
            Object mDelegate = mDelegateField.get(activity);

            Class mDelegateClass = mDelegate.getClass().getSuperclass();
            Field mWindowField = null;

            while (mDelegateClass != null) {
                try {
                    mWindowField = mDelegateClass.getDeclaredField(FIELD_NAME_WINDOW);
                    break;
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException ignored) {
                }

                mDelegateClass = mDelegateClass.getSuperclass();
            }

            if (mWindowField == null)
                throw new NoSuchFieldException(FIELD_NAME_WINDOW);

            mWindowField.setAccessible(true);
            Window mWindow = (Window) mWindowField.get(mDelegate);

            Window.Callback mOriginalWindowCallback = mWindow.getCallback();
            mWindow.setCallback(new AppCompatWindowCallbackCustom(mOriginalWindowCallback, activity));
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class AppCompatWindowCallbackCustom extends WindowCallbackWrapper {

        private WeakReference<AppCompatActivity> mActivityWeak;

        public AppCompatWindowCallbackCustom(Window.Callback wrapped, AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity) {
            super(wrapped);

            mActivityWeak = new WeakReference<AppCompatActivity>(appCompatActivity);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            final int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();

            AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity = mActivityWeak.get();

            if (appCompatActivity != null && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
                if (appCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(event))
                    return true;
            }

            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Call `AppCompatActivityMenuKeyInterceptor.intercept(this)` in the `onCreate` of your activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initialize the interceptor
        AppCompatActivityMenuKeyInterceptor.intercept(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Now onKeyDown is called also for KEYCODE_MENU
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            //do your stuff

            //return false if you want to propagate the
            //KeyEvent to AppCompat, return true otherwise
            return false;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Now onKeyUp is called also for KEYCODE_MENU
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            //do your stuff

            //return false if you want to propagate the
            //KeyEvent to AppCompat, return true otherwise
            return false;
        }

        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

If you use ProGuard or DexGuard add these rules to your configuration:

```
-keepclassmembers class android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity {
    private android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;
}

-keepclassmembers class android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase {
    final android.view.Window mWindow;
}
```

Now your activity can receive `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` event also for the menu key.

Comment: I ran into a problem with this after obfuscating my code.  Keeping the support library seemed to help.  Please comment on this if this seems wrong, but I added to my proguard-rules.pro `-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }`

Comment: @DaiwikDaarun Yes your rules are correct, but you keep all the support libraries. If you want a specific rules you can see the updated answer. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day

Comment: Unfortunately this issue and all the updates are specifically for `KEYCODE_MENU`, not for `KEYCODE_BACK`.

Comment: Excuse me sir, and for those who are not using AppCompat? I'm not being successful capturing KeyUp and KeyDown. Some advice would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `onKeyUp()` or `onKeyDown()`, one can simply use `dispatchKeyEvent()`. Look at the following code from [android-developers.blogspot.com](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html).

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

            // Tell the framework to start tracking this event.
            getKeyDispatcherState().startTracking(event, this);
            return true;

        } else if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            getKeyDispatcherState().handleUpEvent(event);
            if (event.isTracking() && !event.isCanceled()) {
                // DO BACK ACTION HERE
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    } else {
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution doesn't work. The `dispatchKeyEvent` is not propagated when the menu key is pressed while using the v7 support library v22.1.0, v22.1.1 and v22.2.1. It is a known bug and it was fixed in the newest versions of v7 support library.

Comment: It means that hardware menu key press does not even work on 22.0.1

Comment: As you can see in the title this question is specifically for v22.1.0 and higher (v22.1.0, v22.1.1 and v22.2.1)

Comment: Worked great for me on latest SDK.