# onKeyDown event doesn't work for menu button an android phone

Tags: android

I want to block a device's menu button press event.

So far I have used this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    return (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU || super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU || super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event));
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    int action = event.getAction();
    boolean isDown = action == 0;

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        return isDown ? this.onKeyDown(keyCode, event) : this.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

When I press menu button methods `onKeyDown`, `onKeyUp`, `dispatchKeyEvent` are not called. And I see menu list.

Is there another way to block menu button?

PS: I use appcompat-v7:22

Comment: Why?  You control the menu, just don't give it any menu items.

Comment: but I need items in toolbar menu. The problem is that I don`t want to show menu when user clicked menu button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852303/upgraded-to-appcompat-v22-1-0-and-now-onkeydown-and-onkeyup-are-not-triggered-wh

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately AppCompat v22.2.1 broke the onKeyDown and onKeyUp events again. I just updated  v22.2.1.

it is the problem.

Comment: If 22.2.1 broke the events and you updated to 22.2.1 you updated to the broken version? Are you sure that you didn't make a mistake?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is:
MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
(Note: id is of menu item)
menuItem.setEnabled(false);

Comment: This should be a comment as it doesnt answer the question

Comment: Ed I dont have reputation to comment. .And why not answer?It may solve his problem

Comment: I respect the fact you don't have the reputation, but you should still not answer a question unless you're sure what the question is asking. Check out this [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: sorry, I don`t want to block one special item. I want to handle menu button click.