# Android - onKeyDown won't work with KEYCODE_MENU

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Using `onKeyDown` with `KEYCODE_MENU` do nothing but it work with `KEYCODE_SEARCH`

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch(keyCode){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu key pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Search key pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I think there is something handling the menu key so it won't listen to my code
i have tried disbling `onCreateOptionsMenu` like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}
```

But still won't work..
So, any ideas to make the menu button listen to `onKeyDown`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a bug in appcompat v22.  See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159795

The workaround as posted in that thread is to override dispatchKeyEvent :

```
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        int action = event.getAction();
        boolean isDown = action == 0;

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            return isDown ? this.onKeyDown(keyCode, event) : this.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        }

        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

**Edit:** Please see [Upgraded to AppCompat v22.1.0 and now onKeyDown and onKeyUp are not triggered when menu key is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852303/upgraded-to-appcompat-v22-1-0-and-now-onkeydown-and-onkeyup-are-not-triggered-wh/29852304#29852304)

Answer (score 1):

Even in use of Setup Box and Android TV
you can use `dispatchKeyEvent` in `Activity` and after that detect any key you want

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int code = event.getKeyCode();
    int action = event.getAction();
    boolean isDown = action == 0;

    if (code == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What device and OS are you on ?

You may want to update your compat library to the latest .. 
23.0.0